# Sending parameter when opening an app from web

Tags: javascript, ios, deep-linking

Is it possible to pass parameters when opening an app through web via deep link on ios and andriod?

Comment: Also branch.io is a useful tool, but not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters via URL parameters or in the path itself.

https://www.myapp.com/path/5/anotherpath/2

https://www.myapp.com/path/?parameter1=5&parameter2=2

Then you can parse in the receiving Activity. Use helper methods like getQueryParameter() and getPathSegments().